# Autofac with OWIN integration calls wrong constructor

Tags: c#, owin, autofac

I am trying to get a controller class to use a logger, using Autofac.

The controller has 2 constructors, one with 0 parameters and another with 1.

I have followed [this example](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/WebApiExample.OwinSelfHost/Startup.cs) as closely as i could, but for some reason the 0 parameter constructor is being called every time.

My code:

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.Register(c => new Logger()).As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);


  this.ConfigureAuth(app);
```

The controller's constructors:

```
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MailController()
    {

    }

    public MailController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is bad practice to overload constructors like this.  If your class has a dependency sometimes but not others, that is usually a sign that your class really needs to be 2  (or more) classes.

Comment: The empty constructor is just for debugging's sake. I intend to remove it once the problem has been resolved.

Needless to say, if it's removed I get an error (Since the empty constructor is being called)

Comment: Look into https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection.  In this case, if your working in a test environment you can register a TestLogger or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The problem was that I followed an example for OWIN selfhost, While my project wasn't one.

the line

> var config = new HttpConfiguration();

should have been replaced by the line

> var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

Hope this helps Somebody!